# Error when deploying an .ear file containing an MDB to JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am getting the below error while deploying an *enterprise archive jar (.ear)* to JBoss 7.

Can someone please give me pointers on how to resolve this.

The JBoss log is

```
14:44:30,812 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Demo2.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Demo2.jar".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "Demo2.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:447) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:273)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: This looks like a config issue, what type of resource are you trying to look up? What standalone or domain profile are you using?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to deploy application with MDBs to standalone.xml configuration that does not have messaging support enabled. (messaging subsystem is missing)

if you would run server with standalone-full.xml it would work.

you can do that by running:

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

on linux or

```
standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml
```

on windows

Answer (score 6):

In Jboss 7.x we need to add

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            ...
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            ...
```

And hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, found that I was missing

```
<mdb>  
  <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>  
  <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>  
</mdb>
```

under

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
```

in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

Answer (score -1):

On Wildfly 10 it is (also in section  ):

```
    <mdb>
        <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
    </mdb>
```

Comment: You should explain your snippet to make your answer findable.